# Is it possible to recursively use the same activity using intents?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am at a point of code where I need to use same activity with different values. Is it possible to use same activity recursively?

Comment: Recursively, really? Are you saying an activity will contain a new instance of itself? I really don't understand what scenario could warrant a use of recursivity. Can you please elaborate? Are you sure you didn't mean iteratively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its possible but you have to use the condition inside the activity based on the value pass through intents.
  It may possible for the same activity with different values so the value pass from previous activity will decide what data will display..

Answer (score 0):

Yes.you can use the same activity but make sure,you don't go into infinite loop nor you get messed up with different codes for various conditions you call the activity.you can achieve that by maintaining extras in Intent you use to call the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be more suitable (in terms of readability) to create a new Activity-class with the same layout but other functionality? This way one Activity will have one behaviour instead of two - making your code more simple, readable and maintainable.